# flutter connectionstate.waiting cannot load image

Tags: flutter

I have code main.dart like this

```
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: getIsLogin(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
            return LoginScreen();
          }
            return LoginScreen();

        },

      )
```

actually when connection is waiting I want to show splash, but because I have error, so I trying open LoginScreen when connection is waiting or default. in my LoginScreen code I have image and textfield.
when app running and still waiting show my LoginScreen without image, when it's done image is show.
how to show image when connection still waiting?

**(if image is replaced by text it's working while connectionstate is waiting)**

this part of my LoginScreen code

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Masuk",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Image(
            image: AssetImage("asset/images/banner.jpg"),
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  //padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:15.0,right: 15.0,top:0,bottom: 0),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    controller: TFKdCust,
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      if(formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                        enableButton();
                      }else{
                        disableButton();
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Kode Pelanggan',
                        hintText: 'Masukkan Kode Pelanggan Anda'),
                    validator: RequiredValidator(errorText: "Kode Pelanggan tidak boleh kosong"),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 15.0, right: 15.0, top: 15, bottom: 0),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
                    controller: TFPassword,
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      if(formKey.currentState!.validate()){
                        enableButton();
                      }else{
                        disableButton();
                      }
                    },
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        labelText: 'Kata Sandi',
                        hintText: 'Masukkan Kata Sandi Anda'),
                    validator: RequiredValidator(errorText: "Kata Sandi tidak boleh kosong"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited:

You can pass a bool value to the LoginScreen widget.
if it is loading set it to true else false.

```
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: getIsLogin(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return LoginScreen(isLoading: false); // everything is ok!
          } else if(snapshot.hasError){
            return SomeErrorScreen(); // when there is an error
            } else {
            //FutureBuiler has not data, has no error and waiting for the future
            return LoginScreen(isLoading: true);
            }
        },

      )
```

LoginScreen constructor:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isLoading;
  const LoginScreen({required this.isLoading});
```

Then you can check if is it loading show an image else show another image.

```
 children: <Widget>[
            widget.isLoading ?
            Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/loading.jpg"),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ) :
            Image(
              image: AssetImage("assets/login.jpg"),
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
```

This should work.

Try with delayed future:

```
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future<String>.delayed(
          const Duration(seconds: 5),
          () => 'Data Loaded',
        ),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
          return LoginScreen(state: snapshot.connectionState);
        },
      ),
```

Comment: yes, but If I add image in LoadingScreen, image cannot load and show

Comment: it's pass param check if waiting or not, like Purushotam Kumar answer. and I already tried. and I think your answer is similar with that. and this my code after try Purushotam Kumar answer https://pastebin.com/s7N1Kp3C

Comment: I have tested both codes, and they are working fine.

Comment: not for me :(. I don't know why

Comment: try to print some logs.

Comment: print the ConnectionState in the build method, and check the logs

Comment: And try using a delayed future for 5 seconds while debugging.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237660/discussion-between-e-place-and-mhmd-zawi).

Answer (score 1):

Define your `LoginScreen` following way:

```
class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final ConnectionState connectionState;

  const LoginScreen(this.connectionState,);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Masuk",
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          if(connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) // I am making a check here
          Image(
            image: AssetImage("asset/images/banner.jpg"),
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
          ),
        ],

      ),);
  }
```

and your `FutureBuilder` following way

```
FutureBuilder(
      future: getIsLogin(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) =>
          LoginScreen(snapshot.connectionState),
    );
```

depending on your connectionState, it will show the image.

Comment: it's not work, still same. I think it's only move connectionState

Comment: It's not just moving the connection state, depending on the state, inside the LoginScreen I have added one small check as well, made small edit in the answer

Comment: yes I already added check, but still cannot load image

Comment: is it possible for you to share the code, I'll look into it.

Comment: please see my code https://pastebin.com/s7N1Kp3C  . I made different image when is waiting and done. then output only show second image

Answer (score 0):

I actually did not understand from your explanation.

If you want to show a splash screen during the waiting state then do this:

```
   home: FutureBuilder( future: getIsLogin(),
   builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) 
   {
        if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
        return SplashScreen();
   } 
   return LoginScreen();
   })
```

Make a SplashScreen and add the Image you wanna show.

Comment: yes, but if I add image in `SplashScreen`, it's can't load

Comment: when the SplashScreen opens does it show any error? if yes, share the error code.

Comment: also please attach a screenshot of folder where you keeping the asset file and the pubspec.yaml file code screenshot.

Comment: there's no error. it not only image from asset, but image from network can't load too